# How can I integrate Gazebo with ROS Groovy?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Installed ROS Groovy.
I have also installed Gazebo.
Do not know how to integrate it.

I also installed simulator_gazeebo on ROS groovy.
when I am running it using

roslaunch gazebo gazebo

its showing error: not able to connect with master

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66309/how-can-i-integrate-gazebo-with-ros-groovy-?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error "not able to connect with master " usually means you didn't launch the master node. You have to enter "roscore" in your terminal to do so.

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-01**:
Hi, Lucile ...... I have already done that "roscore" is running.